# Non-opensource ads

Tags: feature-request, advertising

As far as I know, SO only offers forum-voted ads for free for Open Source projects (*nothing wrong with that, on the contrary, that's great*).

But I wonder: would it be interesting to open something like 5-10% of ads to commercial ads ?

---

Don't get me wrong, I'm not talking of yet another flashy viagra spam advertisement, but there are other non-opensource projects, services or softwares that would be relevant (and I dare even say interesting) to SO users and would be glad to support the site by paying for ads.

Two examples that are imho successful in doing so: [Fusion Ads](http://fusionads.net) and [Dribbble](http://dribbble.com/site/advertise).

You could still require that the advertised service/product be relevant to programmers and has a high enough graphical quality, yet get some extra cash to support the StackExchange network.

What do you think ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already exists - see [the advertising page](https://stackoverflow.com/about/contact).

Comment: Ah my bad, I didn't think of looking at the **About Us** page for advertising, I stupidely looked at the **More ads** link below the actual ads, which features and mentions only the open source ones, thanks.

Comment: I wish there were more informations on that page except "send a mail if you're interested" which usually means "it's way too expensive for you, forget it unless you're a Microsoft-size company" :(

Comment: @user Considering it's ranked #174 site on Alexa and Microsoft has been a past advertiser, I'd say it probably is quite expensive.